# Perl Regex: Negative look-ahead cross lines

Tags: perl

I have a html file containing ol list of items, each item has the pattern `<li id=ref>xxxxx</li>`, the id "ref" is unique to this list. I want to add a closing `</ol>` after the last item. so I use negative look-ahead to see if the next line has the same id (next line could be any text), if not, `</ol>` tag will be inserted. this is my code

```
$html =~ s`(<li id="ref.*?</li>).*?(?!\<li id="ref)`$1</ol>`gm;
```

the code does not work no matter I use the modifier `s` or `m` at the end of the code.

Comment: You should not [parse HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/725418). Also, you cannot match multiple lines when reading a file in line by line mode.

Comment: `/m` has no effect since your pattern uses neither `^` nor `$`.

Comment: `/s` is probably required since it remove the inability of `.` to match line feeds. But you did not provide a minimal, runnable demonstration of the problem, so I can't be sure.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your replying. I manged to get it to work by using the following code:

```
$html =~ s`</li>(?!.*?id\=\"ref)`</li></ol>`gs;
```